# Playwright test afterEach but with a variable for certain tests

Tags: javascript, playwright, assertion, playwright-test

Each test uses `await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot();`. I wouldn't want to do repetitions in every test.

```js
test.afterEach(async ({ page }) => {
  await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot({mask: [] as Locator[] || null});
});
```

There is a problem. Some tests have dynamic elements that I need to hide. How do I provide an argument/value for `{ mask }` to handle the first case in some tests?

I tried to give the `{ mask }` a value but to no avail:

```
test('should open sender`s grid view', async ({ page }) => {
  // some code 
  {mask: value }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to use `describe` blocks that group the different maskings:

```js
import {test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.30.0

test.describe("with empty mask", () => {
  test.afterEach(async ({page}) => {
    await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot({mask: []});
  });

  test("foo 1", async ({page}) => {
    // ...
  });

  test("foo 2", async ({page}) => {
    // ...
  });
});

test.describe("with p masked", () => {
  test.afterEach(async ({page}) => {
    await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot({
      mask: [page.locator("p")]
    });
  });

  test("bar 1", async ({page}) => {
    // ...
  });

  test("bar 2", async ({page}) => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

If you don't want the describe blocks, there's the more naive pattern of [setting a shared variable](https://playwrightsolutions.com/how-to-conditionally-use-aftereach/) among tests:

```js
import {test} from "@playwright/test";

let mask = [];

test.afterEach(async ({page}) => {
  await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot({mask});
  mask = [];
});

test("foo 1", async ({page}) => {
  // ...
  mask = [page.locator("p"), page.locator("h1")];
});

test("foo 2", async ({page}) => {
  // ...
});

test("foo 3", async ({page}) => {
  // ...
  mask = [page.locator("p")];
});

test("foo 3", async ({page}) => {
  // ...
});
```

The `mask = [];` line ensures that the empty mask is the default value if a test hasn't overridden it.

Note that `[] || null` will never evaluate to `null`, even if the array is empty. If you want to provide `null` as the default value, replace all occurrences of `let mask = []` and `mask = []` with `mask = null`.

Comment: it's possible to make it without a hook. Couse expect(page).toHaveScreenshot() is not included in test

Comment: @ChrystianC Sorry, I don't understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The question is haywire but with this solution every `expect(page).toHaveScreenshot()` s not included in test. There is a way? To make `expect(page).toHaveScreenshot()` was part of each test not a hook `afterEach`.

Comment: I thought that `afterEach` was what you wanted. You can write a function that has your assertion and pass it to each test, or call it from each test. Assertions don't have to be inside the `test` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic elements can be handled using Regex to accommodate many possible scenarios:

```
//Locator definition with regex
const userInfo = page.locator('.user_Info');
const maskedElements = userInfo
    .filter({ hasText: new RegExp(`^Password Info$`) })
```

//some steps

// Assertion with screeenshots with masking

```
await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot({mask: [maskedElements]});
```